# How to add a frequency list in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking to create a histogram with this data. I don't know how to set the count column as the frequency list of the data. When I try to select both columns and make a histogram it just treats the second column as the data set and the first as labels. Instead it should see that for example, height 60 has a frequency of 2. How do I do this?

[image]

Comment: "height 60 has a frequency of 2." In your graphic 60 has a frequency of 8....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variation on a theme per @player0 from StackOverflow: [Google sheets array formula to split and transpose cells with commas into another column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59253298/1330560)

Enter this formula in cell C2:

`=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1,ARRAYFORMULA(REPT(A2:A&",",B2:B))), ","))`

Use the resulting column of values for your histogram.

The logic is:

- `ARRAYFORMULA(REPT(A2:A&",",B2:B))` takes the height value in Column A, and repeats the value by the frequency in Column B. Note the height is described as `A2:A&","` - this puts a comma between each value.
- `TEXTJOIN` - joins all the values in the array; again with a comma as the delimiter
- `SPLIT` - breaks the resulting value at the commas
- `TRANSPOSE` - converts the row of data into a column.

---

**Sample**

[image: Sample]

Comment: This is useful - thank you. However, what if the data transposed is 1 million rows or more. This could crash the browser. Is there any way to build a histogram directly from the 2-column Height x Count table?

Comment: Who is to say that it wouldn’t crash the browser anyway.but maybe you could build it via a script. Have a look at arraytodatatable In the [charts docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/histogram)